# Pointwise limit of continuous functions, but not Riemann integrable.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, pointwise-convergence

I am trying to find a simple example of a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is a pointwise limit of continuous functions, but is not Riemann integrable. I know the classical example where we build some functions $F_1,F_2,\dots$ on a cantor-like set, and then define $f_n = F_1.F_2.\dots . F_n$, and so on. But I was thinking whether there is a simpler example, one that you could present to students with no experience in Measure Theory.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You need a function with a set of discontinuities of positive measure. [The construction in this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_1) (see the characteristic function of the Cantor set; it is approximated by the continuous functions [...]) might be useful. Take a set of positive measure and apply the construction [...]. This yields a sequence of continuous functions converging to a function that is discontinuous precisely of the set you chose previously.